# Are there any tutorials on using sockets for client/server connection with Google App Engine for Java services?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets, client-server

Are  there any tutorials on using sockets for client/server connection with Google App Engine for Java services?

Comment: Jak please don't just copy your question's title into the body. The body of the question is there to specify why you're asking, what you've tried or investigated so far, and to generally give more detail than you can in the title. If you don't *have* any more detail, you probably don't need to ask the question (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sockets are [**not**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) [allowed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) on Google App Engine:

> The restrictions of the sandbox
>   environment are implemented in the
>   JVM. An app can use any JVM bytecode
>   or library feature, as long as it does
>   not exceed the sandbox restrictions.
>   For instance, **bytecode that attempts
>   to open a socket or write to a file
>   will throw a runtime exception.**

Comment: any hacks around this restriction?

Comment: And what about java.net.DatagramSocketImplFactory
java.net.HttpRetryException
java.net.HttpURLConnection
java.net.IDN
java.net.JarURLConnection
java.net.MalformedURLException
java.net.NetPermission
java.net.NetworkInterface
java.net.NoRouteToHostException
java.net.PasswordAuthentication
java.net.PortUnreachableException
java.net.ProtocolException
java.net.Proxy$Type
java.net.SocketException
java.net.SocketImplFactory
java.net.SocketOptions
java.net.SocketPermission
java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: No. There's no other way to get the OS to give Java a network socket. The JVM simply doesn't allow it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You're running in their sandbox.

"[...] bytecode that attempts to open a socket or write to a file will throw a runtime exception.": http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

Comment: And what about JSP page can we open thrue tham?

Comment: That's still bytecode in the JVM, you'll just get an exception when processing the jsp.

Comment: You can make outgoing HTTP requests, as well as sending and receiving email and XMPP messages - just not raw socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said already, raw sockets are forbidden in GAE.

If you need client/server connectivity using GAE as a server and choice of medium is not critical, such connection can be arranged via web-services.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are not allowed, but depending on what it is you are trying to do, you may find that the [XMPP support](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html) is sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a couple years old and there may be up to date responses on SO elsewhere.  However since this came up near top of my search I thought it might be helpful to know that Sockets are now [an experimental feature on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/). Still with some restrictions though.